# What is the meaning of "this [int index]"?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

In C# we have the following interface:

```
public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
{
    T this [int index] { get; set; }
    int IndexOf (T item);
    void Insert (int index, T item);
    void RemoveAt (int index);
}
```

I don't understand the line

```
T this [int index] { get; set; }
```

What does it mean?

Comment: It means you get an extra method `get_Item` and `set_Item` that does the inner workings if you call `myList[myInteger] = foo;` or `T foo = myList[myInteger]` where `foo` is of type `T`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is an indexer defined on the interface. It means you can `get` and `set` the value of `list[index]` for any `IList<T> list` and `int index`.

Documentation: [Indexers in Interfaces (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkyhsw31.aspx)

Consider the `IReadOnlyList<T>` interface:

```
public interface IReadOnlyList<out T> : IReadOnlyCollection<T>, 
    IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
{
    int Count { get; }
    T this[int index] { get; }
}
```

And an example implementation of that interface:

```
public class Range : IReadOnlyList<int>
{
    public int Start { get; private set; }
    public int Count { get; private set; }
    public int this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index < 0 || index >= Count)
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("index");
            }
            return Start + index;
        }
    }
    public Range(int start, int count)
    {
        this.Start = start;
        this.Count = count;
    }
    public IEnumerable<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(Start, Count);
    }
    ...
}
```

Now you could write code like this:

```
IReadOnlyList<int> list = new Range(5, 3);
int value = list[1]; // value = 6
```

Comment: can you tell me the scenario when this cab helpful

Answer (score 14):

That is an indexer. So you can access the instance like an array;

[See MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/index).