# What does "this [string name]" mean in the declaration : "public string this[string name]"

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out what does  `this [string name]` mean in the declaration `public string this[string name]`

Complete Code :

```
public class PersonImplementsIDataErrorInfo : IDataErrorInfo
{
    private int age;

    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set { age = value; }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public string this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            string result = null;

            if (name == "Age")
            {
                if (this.age < 0 || this.age > 150)
                {
                    result = "Age must not be less than 0 or greater than 150.";
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.validatesondataerrors?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: It is an [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers). It provides usage like `personImplementsIDataErrorInfoInstance["name"]`

Comment: @HimBromBeere Would you mind changing the dupe target to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30511571/meaning-of-this-int-index).  That looks to be a better match

Answer (score 5):

It's an [indexer.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/)

> Indexers allow instances of a class or struct to be indexed just like arrays. The indexed value can be set or retrieved without explicitly specifying a type or instance member. Indexers resemble properties except that their accessors take parameters.

In this case, the `PersonImplementsIDataErrorInfo` class contains an indexer of type `string`, that will return a string based on whatever string you send it -

If you send it `Age`, it will return either `null` or `"Age must not be less than 0 or greater than 150."`, if the age property is less than `0` or more than `150`.

Consider the following code:

```
var person = new PersonImplementsIDataErrorInfo() { Age = 167 };

Console.WriteLine(person["Something"]);
Console.WriteLine(person["Age"]);
```

This will result with one blank line (since `Something` will return a null string) and one line that reads `"Age must not be less than 0 or greater than 150."`